# Firebase Firestore email regarding insecure rules

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I recieved a firebase firestore mail today saying:

> Firebase:
> Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules

> We ve detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
> any user can read your entire database

> Because your project does not have strong security rules, anyone can access your entire database. Attackers can read all of your data, and they can drive up your bill.
> Analysis is run daily. If you've modified your rules in the last 24 hours that may not be accounted for.

Is this a warning or is it compulsory to add authentication to my project? I want anyone to be able to read my Firestore database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a warning. You can set rules according to your requirement. However, it is recommended that you secure your database with some sort of rules so that no one can steal your data. For more info read this: [Firebase rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules)

So according to this page in firebase documentation, it is written that "Not recommended: Read and write access to all users." .But nowhere they have mentioned that it is a must.

You can use time rule which has a timestamp as a restriction.

```
   rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
  allow read: if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 12, 1);
     }
      }
        }
```

Comment: they are sending tons of emails to me and it kind of scare me so how to do deal with it

Comment: so how i disable their mails or warning  my security rules are like this rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Hey I only want to allow for read without getting their mails can you help me in that scenario...